# Merging columns in data.frame with "/" symbol

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

For example, I have the following data.frame with 5 columns:

```
1 AAA     123             12              33           0.23                           
2 BBB     3123            44              22           0.55                           
3 CCC     221             45              11           0.44
```

From this data frame I want to create new, which looks like the following:

```
    1 AAA     123/12         33/0.23                                      
    2 BBB     3123/44        22/0.55                                      
    3 CCC     221/45         11/0.44
```

How can I merge columns (2&3 and 4&5) with the separator "/"?

Of course the variables should be character.

Comment: Have you tried it with the function `paste()`?

Comment: `library(zoo)` is helpful here...something like `cbind(df[1], t(rollapply(t(df[-1]), 2, by = 2, paste, collapse = '/')))` should also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can loop through the second and fourth column index, get the columns based on the index and `paste` it together, and `cbind` with the first column of original dataset.

```
cbind(df[1], do.call(cbind, lapply(c(2,4), function(i) 
                   do.call(paste, c(df[i:(i+1)], sep="/")))))
```

---

Or another option is `unite` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    unite(col2_col3, col2, col3, sep="/") %>%
    unite(col4_col5, col4, col5, sep="/")
```

Comment: @Dan_yef The `df[1]` is the first column with 'AAA', 'BBB' etc.   is still a data.frame and when we cbind with the output of `lapply`, it is still a data.frame, In the `lapply`, we loop by column index 2 and 4, then we add `i:(i+1)` i.e. 2:3 and 4:5, subset the columns of 'df', and `paste` it together

Comment: Worth noting first solution can scale programmatically in case of many more columns, e.g.: `seq(2,ncol(df),2)` instead of `c(2,4)`.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
cbind(df[,1], sapply(c(2,4), function(x)  paste0(df[,x],"/",df[,x+1])))
```

Answer (score 1):

This will also do:

```
cbind.data.frame(df[1:2], 
                 V3=paste(df[,3], df[,4],sep='/'),
                 V4=paste(df[,5], df[,6],sep='/'))

V1  V2      V3      V4
1  1 AAA  123/12 33/0.23
2  2 BBB 3123/44 22/0.55
3  3 CCC  221/45 11/0.44
```

Comment: Try doing this for 100 columns.